# FCBKcomplete, Create a new TAG with Commas as opposed to Enter

Tags: autocomplete, tags, autosuggest, fcbkcomplete

Currently, FCBKcomplete created new tags after you type something in and press enter. Is there a way to get the plug-in to allow for comma's (which is how tags are commonly separated) to create new tags?

I'd hate to have to try to retrain users to user enter as opposed to the more standard comma separator. 
Plugin: http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html

Demo (use the second control): http://www.emposha.com/demo/fcbkcomplete_2/

Comment: This is not related to fckeditor, its name comes from facebook-complete. That tag should be removed

Answer (score 2):

The options to create tags using commas, tabs and keep the focus was just added in this fork:
http://github.com/steve-newicon/FCBKcomplete ( version 2.7.5 )

It works cause I'm using it.

Comment: was this change ever released in the main site?

Comment: I really don't know. I haven't worked with it since that last project. Checkout the repository.